# How do you use secure websockets with Photon realtime Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, ssl, photon

I've got things to work when starting the client with `Photon.ConnectionProtocol.Ws`, but whenever I use `Photon.ConnectionProtocol.Wss`  I get the following error:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://app-eu.exitgamescloud.com:19090/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled

I found documentation on the site about enabling secure websockets, but that seemed to be for when you're connecting to your own server, and you can put an SSL certificate on it. What do I need to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

When working with Photon cloud, you should connect to nameserver instead of master server.

Calling connectToRegionMaster({region code}) is the simplest way to do so. It will connect to ws://ns.exitgames.com:9093 or wss://ns.exitgames.com:19093 automatically depending on chosen protocol.

If you need to choose region from list of available regions before connect, use sequence of connectToNameServer, getRegions, connectToRegionMaster methods.
You can find more details in online documentation http://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/javascript/current/Photon.LoadBalancing.LoadBalancingClient.html